# DNS ECS (Client Subnet) not working for Route53 GeoBalanced record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a geo balanced DNS record using `AWS Route53`. It's setup to resolve to `127.0.0.1` for requests issued from USA area and `54.1.1.1` from anywhere else.

When I run a DNS Query using the AWS authoritative NS and passing a USA IP Address in the client subnet all works fine:

[image: With AWS DNS]

You can see it is resolving to 127.0.0.1 as I would expect.

However, if I try to run the same query using Google DNS it resolves to 54.1.1.1:

[image: With Google DNS]

**Why does this happen?**

In the response from Google's DNS the CLIENT-SUBNET field looks correct, which makes it even more confusing. My guess would be an intermediate NS is causing this, but I haven't been able to prove it.
I am using a [patched version](https://www.gsic.uva.es/~jnisigl/dig-edns-client-subnet.html) of `dig` with support for the `+client` option.

Comment: Google doesn’t forward a /32, but a /24 per the rfc.  Try setting 45.63.111.0/24 in your dig.

Comment: @imperalix same result for /24

Comment: I was trying to test on dns.google.com but it looks like your record is no longer there.

Comment: @imperalix Sorry, I have put the records back now.

Comment: Looks like google maybe stripping it before it recurses.   https://dns.google.com/query?name=geotest.devpanda.co.uk.&type=A&dnssec=true&ecs=45.63.111.0%2F24 looks to return what you expect.